# Lazy @LastModifiedBy

Tags: spring, hibernate

How to lazy load many-to-one column with @LastModifiedBy annotation?

For example I have createdBy and lastModifiedBy columns:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
private User manager;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@CreatedBy
@JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonProperty("created_user_id")
private User createdBy;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@LastModifiedBy
@JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonProperty("last_modified_user_id")
private User lastModifiedBy;
```

It's work. But as soon as I try to lazy load column lastModifiedBy (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false) I have error:

```
2016-06-18 23:10:36,399 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-8) Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Problem accessing property 'id': null (through reference chain: com.smcontact.cms.model.project.Project["manager"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem accessing property 'id': null (through reference chain: com.smcontact.cms.model.project.Project["manager"])
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: register hibernate module.

```
Hibernate5Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();
objectMapper.registerModule(hibernateModule);
```